# Java application with TCP sockets is using 100% of CPU

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

The server has to continuously listen for incoming connections and perform some logic on the data received. Every time I run the application, the CPU usage is more than 90%. Earlier I thought that the while loop might be spinning (busy waiting), but the readLine() is supposed to be a blocking call, so I don't think that is the case. Any help is appreciated!
The following is the server code:

```
public void listen() throws IOException
    {

        try( ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
             Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
             DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
             BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));)
        {

            String data = null;
            while((data = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                Message message = Message.deserializeMessage(data);
                synchronized (PeerNode.requestHistory)
                {
                    if(PeerNode.requestHistory.keySet().contains(message)) 
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                if(message.getType() == 0 && message.getHopCount() < 1) {
                    continue;
                }
                switch(message.getType()) {
                    case 0:
                        synchronized (PeerNode.sharedRequestBuffer){ 
                              PeerNode.sharedRequestBuffer.offer(message);
                            }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        synchronized (PeerNode.sharedReplyBuffer) {
                             PeerNode.sharedReplyBuffer.offer(message);
                        }

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        synchronized (PeerNode.numberOfItems) {
                            if(PeerNode.numberOfItems > 0) {
                                PeerNode.numberOfItems -= 1;
                            }
                            outputStream.writeBytes("0" + "\n");
                        }
                        break;
                }
                synchronized (PeerNode.requestHistory) {
                    PeerNode.requestHistory.put(message, 0);
                }
            }
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
               ex.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
```

Edit: Added deserialize() method

```
public static Message deserializeMessage(String s)
    {
        Message m = new Message();
        String[] objArray = s.split("#");
        String[] list = objArray[2].split(",");
        m.setProductName(objArray[0]); 
        m.setProductId(Integer.parseInt(objArray[1]));
        List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList();
        for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++)
        {
            if(list[i].length() == 0)
                continue;
            tempList.add(Integer.parseInt(list[i]));
        }
        m.setMessagePath(tempList);
        m.setHopCount(Integer.parseInt(objArray[3]));
        m.setType(Integer.parseInt(objArray[4]));
        m.setRequestId(Integer.parseInt(objArray[5]));
        m.setSourcePeerId(Integer.parseInt(objArray[6]));
        m.setDestinationSellerId(Integer.parseInt(objArray[7]));
        m.setDestinationSellerLocation(Integer.parseInt(objArray[8]));
        return m;
    }
```

Edit 2: Changed deserialize() to use Scanner():

```
public static Message deserializeMessage(String s)

{
        Message m = new Message();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
        sc.useDelimiter("#");
        m.setProductName(sc.next());
        m.setProductId(Integer.parseInt(sc.next()));
        List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList();
        Scanner sct = new Scanner(sc.next());
        sct.useDelimiter(",");
        while(sct.hasNext())
        {
            tempList.add(Integer.parseInt(sct.next()));
        }
        m.setMessagePath(tempList);
        m.setHopCount(Integer.parseInt(sc.next()));
        m.setType(Integer.parseInt(sc.next()));
        m.setRequestId(Integer.parseInt(sc.next()));
        m.setSourcePeerId(Integer.parseInt(sc.next()));
        m.setDestinationSellerId(Integer.parseInt(sc.next()));
        m.setDestinationSellerLocation(Integer.parseInt(sc.next()));
        return m;
}
```

Edit: Updated Server Code:

```
private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);
public void listen() throws IOException
    {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            try
            {
                //Server, Listening........
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                ServerExecutor serverExecutor = new ServerExecutor(peerID, clientSocket);
                executor.submit(serverExecutor);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        serverSocket.close();
    }
```

ServerExecutor class:

```
 public ServerExecutor(int _peerID, Socket _clientSocket)
    {
        this.peerID = _peerID;
        this.clientSocket = _clientSocket;
    }
public void run() 
    {

        try( DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
             BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));)
        {

            String data = null;
            while((data = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                Message message = Message.deserializeMessage(data);
                synchronized (PeerNode.requestHistory)
                {
                    if(PeerNode.requestHistory.keySet().contains(message)) 
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                if(message.getType() == 0 && message.getHopCount() < 1) {
                    continue;
                }
                switch(message.getType()) {
                    case 0:
                        synchronized (PeerNode.sharedRequestBuffer){ 
                              PeerNode.sharedRequestBuffer.offer(message);
                            }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        synchronized (PeerNode.sharedReplyBuffer) {
                             PeerNode.sharedReplyBuffer.offer(message);
                        }

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        synchronized (PeerNode.numberOfItems) {
                            if(PeerNode.numberOfItems > 0) {
                                PeerNode.numberOfItems -= 1;
                            }
                            outputStream.writeBytes("0" + "\n");
                        }
                        break;
                }
                synchronized (PeerNode.requestHistory) {
                    PeerNode.requestHistory.put(message, 0);
                }
            }
            clientSocket.close();

         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
               ex.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
```

Updated deserialize():

```
public static Message deserializeMessage(String s)
    {
        Message m = new Message();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
        sc.useDelimiter("#");
        m.setProductName(sc.next());
        m.setProductId(sc.nextInt());
        List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList();
        Scanner sct = new Scanner(sc.next());
        sct.useDelimiter(",");
        while(sct.hasNext())
        {
            tempList.add(sct.nextInt());
        }
        m.setMessagePath(tempList);
        m.setHopCount(sc.nextInt());
        m.setType(sc.nextInt());
        m.setRequestId(sc.nextInt());
        m.setSourcePeerId(sc.nextInt());
        m.setDestinationSellerId(sc.nextInt());
        m.setDestinationSellerLocation(sc.nextInt());
        return m;
}
```

Comment: The problem is obviously with 'some logic on the same thread'. This kind of boilerplate is used all over the Internet, and it does not occupy 100% of CPU. Although if you're using `BufferedReader` for input you should obviously be using `BufferedWriter` for output.

Comment: The logic is basically adding objects to a shared concurrent data structure, which is used by different threads. I will change it to BufferedWriter, thanks!

Comment: It is no use whatsoever merely telling us what you think it does.  Post it so we can find the problem in it.

Comment: I have added the logic as well, please have a look

Comment: Your code is still incomplete without the deserialization method, but it contains a thread-safety issue at `synchronized (PeerNode.numberOfItems) `. Evidently this is an `Integer`, or maybe a `Long`, any some boxed integral type, but they are all atomic, so the following updates will produce a *new* one, so the synchronization can't work. Use an `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: The deserialize message converts the string message to an object of the Message class

Comment: No kidding. Again you are just telling us what you think it does without showing it. Again you have done so after already being told that your post is incomplete. Again we cannot comment on your code without seeing it all. Something in your code, *other than what you've posted,* is consuming 100% CPU. Your question remains unanswerable in its present form.

Comment: Added the deserialize() method

Comment: Throw it away and use a `Scanner`. This method creates tons of garbage.

Comment: Changed to `Scanner`. Still more than 90% usage.

Comment: Sigh. Changed it to `Scanner` *how?* How do you expect us to comment on code we can't see? Why do you have to have every last piece of code prised out of you by *force majeure*?

Comment: I'm sorry, new to StackOverflow. Added the code

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you're new to SO or been here 10 years. It's just common sense that people can't comment on what they can't see, and anyway you should have got the hint the fist time. Instead of continuing to do everything the hard way and letting a thousand strings bloom, `Integer.parseInt(sc.next())` should be `sc.nextInt()` throughout. I would also ask whether the integer fields in `Message` are `int` or `Integer`. If the latter, don't. Use `int`.  My next queston is whether the peer is sending this data continuously as fast as it can go?

Comment: I am using `int` in the fields. Multiple clients are connecting to this server,  sending one line of data, and closing the connection. This part of the code will only send data in case 2.

Comment: I have added the updated code

Answer (score -1):

Are you using different thread for each new client connection and also this kinda code will never occupy such a high % of CPU load. Is there some other functionality that's running in the background as well? 
Edit:
Maybe you can try something like this?

```
while (true)  
{ 
    Socket s = null; 
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5555);
    try 
    { 
            s = ss.accept(); //ss is the server socket object
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader int = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            //create a new Thread for the client
            Thread t = new TaskHandler(s, in, out); //run method of Task Handler can have the code you want to execute for each connected client
            t.start(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception e){ 
            s.close(); 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: No, he is processing each connection in the accept loop. Read the code.

Comment: No, I am using the same thread for each connection. I was not sure as this is my first time programming with sockets. This is the server code for a P2P system, so many applications with identical code are running simultaneously in the background

Comment: How would putting the same 100%-CPU-using code into a separate thread change the CPU usage?